# How to access files(display,move) on other computers connected over LAN using java?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on load balancing project. I need access to the file on another computer connected to mine over LAN so that I could balance the disk space of that computer. Is there any way possible to do this using java? like how i can display all the files stored in the other computer in something like a tree?? using java.

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't provide a native method to achieve that. The easiest way might be to use NFS mount the other computers' disks to your computer, then your Java code could operate those remote disk just like local disk.

Comment: What's NFS?? :( Can you please explain how to use it?? and how i can integrate with my java program??.I'm very poor in technology aspect.

Comment: NFS standards for Network File System. On most Unix/Linux OS, NFS is a builtin feature (but that doesn't mean NFS will be installed by default.) NSF is independent on Java. As long as a remote disk mounts to your computer, you may access the remote disk just like a local folder. You may easily google NFS for more information.

Comment: Is is possible to download NFS for Windows 8?? Can you provide me with a download link?? Please??

Comment: Google for NFS.  Some here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/freenfs/ or even http://www.freenas.org/

Comment: @user2179089 I know Windows supports NFS, but I don't have any experience on win8 yet. I usually work on Linux.

Comment: I thinks that's how I'm supposed to do it. I'll try it out and let you know if it works in sometimes. Thank you so much for answering.

Comment: :( :( I've been trying to mount NFS but i couldn't :(. Can you pls help me out more??

Comment: I can just give you some common concept. For detailed procedure, I'm afraid I cannot because I'm not familiar with Windows NSF either. You have run a NFS server on your remote computer, and run a NFS mount client on your local computer. Then you can mount remote disk to your local computer. I'm not sure if MS Win supports NFS natively, but at least you should be able to find third part NFS applications (server and client).

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to share the file over the Network, and give the remote computer read/write permissions to all the files. Then you can use the java.nio classes to do it very easily:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MoveRemoteFiles
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String originalLocation = "\\\\NETWORK-LOCATION\\MyFile.txt";
        String newLocation = "\\\\NETWORK-LOCATION\\MyFile_2.txt";

        Path originalPath = Paths.get(originalLocation);
        Files.move(originalPath, Paths.get(newLocation));
    }
}
```

And regarding the listing of all files, I'd recommend using the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io//) library with the `FileUtils.listFiles()` method to save time engineering your own solution, like so:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class ListRemoteFiles
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String originalLocation = "\\\\NETWORK-LOCATION\\Folder\\";

        //List all files of all extensions (No Folders)
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(originalLocation), null, true);
        //List all files and folders
        Collection<File> filesAndFolders = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs
                                           (
                                               new File(originalLocation),
                                               TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE,
                                               TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE
                                           );
    }
}
```

And then you can use the method above to move them after.

Comment: I've tried that already and its not working :( .

Comment: @user2179089 Are you able to navigate to and read the file manually through the Networking page in Windows Explorer? And what error do you get when you run it?

Comment: Sorry i tried without turning on the file sharing option in the network properties. Move is working but i need to know the directories and folders available in the other computer to move those file. Its like i want to balance the disk spaces available in that computer by running the code in mine. I'm basically assuming these two computers as two servers, since my project is about balancing the load between two file servers automatically without human intervension.

Comment: @user2179089 See edits.